# how to cast the hexadecimal to varchar(datetime)?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, datetime

I have the datetime exporting is  "CAST(0x0000987C00000000 AS DateTime)" but when I want to get it back into datetime.It is a NULL value. how can i get it to datetime again.

Comment: What kind of datetime value do you expect from this? Not sure I understand.

Comment: Oh boy... How did you come up with this hexadecimal value?

Comment: Returns `2006-11-17 00:00:00.000` for me in SQL Server. Are you trying to use the SQL Server binary format in MySQL? Not sure why you would want to do this but anyway it is stored as 2 integers with the first 4 bytes being the days since 1st jan 1900 and the 2nd being the number of ticks since midnight (each tick being 0.33ms)

Comment: How can i get 2006-11-17?.Because, I use it im mysql but it return null.

Comment: You can use `SELECT cast('1900-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL CAST(0x0000987C AS SIGNED) DAY + INTERVAL CAST(0x00000000 AS SIGNED)/300 second as datetime)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That looks like the SQL Server `datetime` format. Internally this is stored as 2 integers with the first 4 bytes being the days since 1st jan 1900 and the 2nd being the number of ticks since midnight (each tick being 1/300 of a second).

If you need to use this in MySQL you could do

```
SELECT 
      CAST(
          '1900-01-01 00:00:00' + 
          INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX(BinaryData),1,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED) DAY +
          INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX(BinaryData),9,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED)* 10000/3 MICROSECOND
      AS DATETIME) AS converted_datetime
FROM
(
SELECT 0x0000987C00000000 AS BinaryData
UNION ALL
SELECT 0x00009E85013711EE AS BinaryData
) d
```

Returns

```
converted_datetime
--------------------------
2006-11-17 00:00:00
2011-02-09 18:52:34.286667
```

(Thanks to Ted Hopp for [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948062/working-with-binary-data-in-mysql/4948307#4948307) in splitting the binary data)

Comment: My sqlserver export into this format("CAST(0x0000987C00000000 AS DateTime)") and I have more migrate data datetime into mysql so,how i can do.

Comment: @Martin: `SELECT HEX(0x0000987C00000000 & 0xFFFFFFFF), HEX(0x0000987C00000000 >> 32);`

Comment: @Mhcl - Thanks! Any idea why `CAST(substr(BinaryData,1,4)  AS SIGNED)` doesn't work? If I just do `SELECT substr(BinaryData,1,4)` and look at it in the BLOB viewer in SQL workbench it looks identical to that shown if I do `SELECT 0x0000987C`

Comment: @Mhcl - That doesn't work when I try and plug it into my answer. `cast(HEX(0x0000987C00000000 >> 32)as signed)` returns `987` it seems to treat it as a string not binary. Any ideas?

Comment: I've added `HEX()` just for visualtion purposes. Do `SELECT cast(0x0000987C00000000 >> 32 as signed);`

Comment: @Martin and Mhcl - Thxs so much for all the answer and suggest.Its very helpful for me. ^^

Comment: @Mhcl - That works when I hardcode the value in twice but stops working when I try and only do it once. `SELECT cast(BinaryData >> 32 as signed),cast(BinaryData & 0xFFFFFFFF as signed) FROM (SELECT 0x0000987C00000000 AS BinaryData) d` I've asked [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948062/working-with-binary-data-in-mysql) on this area you might be able to answer.

Answer (score 8):

Not really adding anything that hasn't been stated but I used this to create a MySql function from the above code.  I can then use a RegEx find and replace (in Notepad++) to replace the CAST(0xblahblahblah AS DATETIME) with sp_ConvertSQLServerDate(0xblahblahblah).

```
create function sp_ConvertSQLServerDate(dttm binary(16))
returns datetime
return CAST(
      '1900-01-01 00:00:00' + 
      INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX(dttm),1,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED) DAY +
      INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX(dttm),9,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED)* 10000/3 MICROSECOND
AS DATETIME);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to help convert something from SiteFinity to WordPress.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is the same select statement for **PostgreSQL**:

```
SELECT '1900-01-01 00:00:00'::date +
    (('x'||substring(x::text,3,8))::bit(32)::int::text||'days')::interval +
    ((('x'||substring(x::text,11,8))::bit(32)::int /300)::text||' seconds')::interval
FROM (VALUES 
    ('0x00009fff00e24076'),
    ('0x00009ff10072d366'),
    ('0x00009ff10072ce3a'),
    ('0x00009ff10072c5e2'),
    ('0x00009ff10072bc3c'))  as x(x);
```

PostgreSQL bit(32) values have to start with 'x' value instead of 0.

Comment: This question is tagged MySql. Please consider adding this answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7580700/73226

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Java program I did.

The the program scans the given file (change de name on the code below) for

```
CAST(0x... AS DateTime)
```

and replaces them with their respective

```
CAST('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' AS DateTime)
```

.

For instance, considering that `SELECT CAST (0x00009CEF00A25634 as datetime)` returns `2009-12-30 09:51:03.000`, the program scans the file for `CAST(0x00009CEF00A25634 AS DateTime)` and replaces them with `CAST('2009-12-30 09:51:03.000' AS DateTime)`.

I used it to convert a SQL Server generated script into something a H2 embedded database could understand.

Altough it worked fine for me, I advise you check it (just run on some test data and see) before using on actual data.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class ReplaceHexDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputFile = "C:/input.sql";
        String inputEncoding = "UTF-8";
        String outputFile = "C:/input-replaced.sql";
        String outputEncoding = "UTF-8";

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile), inputEncoding));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile), outputEncoding));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.indexOf("CAST(0x") > -1) {
                bw.write(replaceHexWithDate(line));
            } else {
                bw.write(line);
            }
            bw.newLine();
        }
        br.close();
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    }

    private static String replaceHexWithDate(String sqlLine) throws ParseException {
        Pattern castPattern = Pattern.compile("(CAST\\()(0x[A-Fa-f0-9]{16})( AS DateTime\\))");
        Matcher m = castPattern.matcher(sqlLine);
        while (m.find()) {
            String s = m.group(2);
            sqlLine = sqlLine.replace(s, "'"+sqlServerHexToSqlDate(s)+"'");
        }
        return sqlLine;
    }

    public static String sqlServerHexToSqlDate(String hexString) throws ParseException {
        String hexNumber = hexString.substring(2); // removes the leading 0x
        String dateHex = hexNumber.substring(0, 8);
        String timeHex = hexNumber.substring(8, 16);

        long daysToAdd = Long.parseLong(dateHex, 16);
        long millisToAdd = (long) (Long.parseLong(timeHex, 16) *10/3);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

        Calendar startingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String startingDate = "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000";
        startingCal.setTime(sdf.parse(startingDate));

        Calendar convertedCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        convertedCal.setTime(sdf.parse(startingDate));
        convertedCal.add(Calendar.DATE, (int) daysToAdd);
        convertedCal.setTimeInMillis(convertedCal.getTimeInMillis() + millisToAdd);

        return sdf.format(convertedCal.getTime());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using notepad++ regex replace

```
cast[(]0x([0-9A-F]{16}) As DateTime[)]

CAST('1900-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX( 0x\1 ),1,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED) DAY + INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX( 0x\1 ),9,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED)* 10000/3 MICROSECOND AS DATETIME)
```

This will replace

```
CAST(0x0000A26900F939A8 AS DateTime)
```

to

```
CAST('1900-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX( 0x0000A26900F939A8 ),1,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED) DAY + INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX( 0x0000A26900F939A8 ),9,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED)* 10000/3 MICROSECOND AS DATETIME),
```

Answer (score 1):

MSSQL hex code for date and dateTime are different.

For date in fomate like 0x00000000 you can use this postgres function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION convertedata(text) RETURNS timestamp without time zone
as $$ SELECT '0001-01-01 00:00:00'::date + (('x'||
(regexp_replace(
substring($1::text,3,8)::text,
 '(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)',
 '\4\3\2\1'))::text
)::bit(32)::int::text||'days')::interval $$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

then try

```
select convertedata('0x0E360B00')
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking a solution in C#. For example when reading scripted database data.

```
        string pattern = @"CAST\(0x(\w{8})(\w{8}) AS DateTime\)";
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
        Match m = r.Match(hex);            

        int d = System.Convert.ToInt32("0x" + m.Groups[1].Value, 16);
        int t = System.Convert.ToInt32("0x" + m.Groups[2].Value, 16);

        DateTime converted = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddDays(d).AddSeconds(t/300);
```

Here I used regex since my input is in the following form "CAST(0x0000A53E00E1A17B AS DateTime)", but you can use SubString() or whatever to get the DateTime string.