# CAST(0x00009F0900000000 AS DateTime) with Ruby or MySql

Tags: mysql, ruby, casting

I'm trying to convert this string "0x00009F0900000000" into a date either through MySql or Rails as I'm working on a migration.

Can't find what format it is. Doesn't look like there's a way to convert hexadecimal value into a date through rails or mysql.

**Solution found here: [how to cast the hexadecimal to varchar(datetime)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946292/how-to-cast-the-hexadecimal-to-varchardatetime)**

```
SELECT 
      CAST(
          '1900-01-01 00:00:00' + 
          INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX(BinaryData),1,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED) DAY +
          INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX(BinaryData),9,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED)* 10000/3 MICROSECOND
      AS DATETIME) AS converted_datetime
FROM
(
SELECT 0x00009F0900000000 AS BinaryData
) d
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know precisely what format it's in, as that is what the answer depends upon

Comment: or at least, which date this string is interpreted to in the old application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to cast the hexadecimal to varchar(datetime)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946292/how-to-cast-the-hexadecimal-to-varchardatetime)

Comment: `select CAST(0x00009F0900000000 AS DateTime)` in SQL Server gives `2011-06-21 00:00:00.000`

Comment: Thanks Martin it was indeed a duplicate sorry.

Comment: Well, that's quite a way to store a date!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ruby (and ignoring time)

```
require 'date'
str =  "0x00009F0900000000"
p Date.new(1900,1,1) + str[0..9].hex
#<Date: 2011-06-21 ((2455734j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I found to your question:

```
> "0x00009F0900000000".to_i(16)
 => 174861003522048 
> time = "0x00009F0900000000".to_i(16)
 => 174861003522048 


> Time.at(time/1000)
 => 7511-02-16 05:58:42 +0100 


> Time.at(time/1000000)
 => 1975-07-17 21:30:03 +0100
```

Try several divisors till you get what should be accurate

Comment: Thanks I tried but couldn't find something accurate easily. I added the solution in my post.