# CAST(0x993902CE AS DATETIME) FROM SQL SERVER TO MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

Does anyone knows how to `CAST(0x993902CE AS DATETIME)` from SQL SERVER ([`smalldatetime` binary format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)) to MYSQL?

I tried `CAST(0X993902CE AS DATETIME)` in mysql but it returns NULL when it should return '2007-05-25 11:58:00'.

If anyone can tell me a way to do this, I'd be grateful.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `0x993902CE` is a UNIX timestamp? Try `FROM_UNIXTIME(0x993902CE)` instead. I cannot test it at the moment, so I won't submit it as an answer.

Comment: Are you trying to convert this on the mysql side?

Comment: @VincentSavard How can I use FROM_UNIXTIME(0x993902CE) in MYSQL syntax?

Comment: @evolquez: It's the `FROM_UNIXTIME` function, but from my tests it doesn't return what you're looking for, so I wouldn't expect it to work. I'm not sure what the number `0x993902CE` represents, actually.

Comment: @MartinSmith You are right, but what I try is convert or cast it to DATETIME in MYSQL

Comment: @VincentSavard :If I try 'CAST(0x993902CE AS SmallDateTime)' in SQL-SERVER it should return '2007-07-02 00:00:00', I need to do the same but using MYSQL.

Comment: @evolquez: Yes, I understood what you wanted to do. That doesn't explain, however, what the number is supposed to be.

Comment: `SELECT CAST(0x9939 AS INT) , CAST(0x02CE AS INT)`  gives `39225` and `718` which is days after January 1, 1900 and number of minutes since midnight respectively.` [My answer to a similar question could be used as a start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946292/how-to-cast-the-hexadecimal-to-varchardatetime/4946759#4946759)

Comment: @VincentSavard: using SQLS-SERVER as SmallDateTime sintax it returns '2007-07-02 00:00:00'

Comment: @MartinSmith: You're absolutely right, it returns 2007-05-25 11:58:00, excuse me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following @MartinSmith's earlier suggestion in the comments and solution I wrote this simple code

```
SELECT "0x993902CE" INTO @raw_data;

SELECT conv(substr(@raw_data, 3, 4), 16, 10) INTO @days;
SELECT conv(substr(@raw_data, 7, 4), 16, 10) INTO @minutes;
SELECT "1900-01-01 00:00:00" INTO @start_date;
SELECT date_add(@start_date, interval @days DAY) INTO @date_plus_years;
SELECT date_add(@date_plus_years, interval @minutes MINUTE) INTO @final_date;

SELECT @final_date;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c960a/37

You can ofcourse inline everything or put it into a function, this is more of a proof of concept.