# How to convert SQLServer "CAST(0xBB330B00 AS Date)" to MySQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, matlab

I have a script from an SQL Server database that includes statements such as this:

```
INSERT SPECIAL_DAYS_TABLE (Date, Description) VALUES (CAST(0xB5330B00 AS Date), 'Christmas')
```

My question: how can I convert this into valid MySQL syntax?
The cast part returns a null date value...

Unfortunately, I have no access to the SQLServer database, do direct data import is impossible - the script is the only thing that I can work with.

Note: there are hundreds of such statements, so I need to programmatically convert the cast part either in MySQL or outside MySQL (C/Java/Matlab/VB).

EDIT: answer closed as per [how to cast the hexadecimal to varchar(datetime)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946292/how-to-cast-the-hexadecimal-to-varchardatetime) and the correction by Martin in the comment below

Apparently, the 0xB5330B00 should be interpreted as 0x000B33B5 (i.e., reverse the bytes) = 734133 (days since 0001-Jan-01)

```
CAST('0001-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL CAST(0x000B33B5 AS SIGNED) DAY as date) => 2010-12-28
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946292/how-to-cast-the-hexadecimal-to-varchardatetime

Comment: The potential duplicate is for `datetime` which is 8 bytes. The format you have is only 4 bytes. Internal storage of `Date` in SQL Server is different from `datetime`. `SELECT CAST(0xB5330B00 AS Date)` in SQL Server gives `2010-12-28`

Comment: @Martin - thanks for the clarification - I updated the text above accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [how to cast the hexadecimal to varchar(datetime)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946292/how-to-cast-the-hexadecimal-to-varchardatetime) and the correction by Martin in the comment below, apparently, the 0xB5330B00 should be interpreted as 0x000B33B5 (i.e., reverse the bytes) = 734133 (days since 0001-Jan-01)

So the full answer is:

```
INSERT SPECIAL_DAYS_TABLE (Date, Description) VALUES (CAST('0001-01-01' + INTERVAL 0x000B33B5 DAY as date), 'Christmas')
```

Note the differences between this question/solution and the one referenced above:

- For `datetime`, the baseline SQLServer date is 1900-01-01; for `date` it is 0001-01-01
- For `datetime`, there are 8 bytes in hex format that *should not* be reversed (left-most 4 bytes is the date, right-most 4 bytes is the time); for `date` there are only 4 bytes that *should* be reversed

In summary, here is a sample Matlab code to convert SQLServer `date` and `datetime` objects into equivalent MySql syntax:

```
% Convert dates in MATLAB from SQLServer => MySQL

% Datetime: byte order is NOT reversed & start date is 1/1/1900
str = regexprep(str, 'CAST\(0x(........)(........) AS DateTime\)', ...
                     'CAST(''1900-01-01'' + INTERVAL 0x$1 DAY + INTERVAL 0x$2/300 second as datetime)');

% Date: byte order is reversed & start date is 1/1/0001
str = regexprep(str, 'CAST\(0x(..)(..)(..)(..) AS Date\)', ...
                     'CAST(''0001-01-01'' + INTERVAL 0x$4$3$2$1 DAY as date)');
```

This snippet can easily be adapted for other programming languages.