# How to convert MSSQL to MySQL date in PHP

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am a PHP developer and I am working in converting MSSQL to MySQL file while converting data's

```
CAST(0x063A0B00 AS Date)
```

I cant convert this as a `timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      CAST(
          '1900-01-01 00:00:00' + 
          INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX(BinaryData),1,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED) DAY +
          INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX(BinaryData),9,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED)* 10000/3 MICROSECOND
      AS DATETIME) AS converted_datetime
FROM
(
SELECT 0x0000987C00000000 AS BinaryData
UNION ALL
SELECT 0x00009E85013711EE AS BinaryData
) d
```

From [how to cast the hexadecimal to varchar(datetime)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946292/how-to-cast-the-hexadecimal-to-varchardatetime)