# How to parse SQL Server binary date format in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, hex

How to convert `CAST(0xE3350B00 AS DATE)` to **mysql** ?

I used various forum supports and have following results

```
0xE3350B00 => 2059-04-03 22:56
0x0000A17F00000000 => 2013-03-12
```

But both dates belong to same line of data so i am confident that `0xE3350B00` should convert to nearby `2013-03-12` but not finding it technically? Can anyone help if conversion of `0xE3350B00` date??

I used following code in sql function:

```
return date_add(date_add("1900-01-01 00:00:00", interval conv(substr(HEX(raw_data), 5, 4), 16, 10) DAY), interval conv(substr(HEX(raw_data), 1, 4), 16, 10) MINUTE);
```

Comment: Removed `Sql Server` which is irrelevant to current question

Comment: @MartinSmith I didnt find anything related to sql server in question except your assumption

Comment: @VR46 - The tag was a pretty big clue that you removed. With that context and actually trying `SELECT CAST(0xE3350B00 AS DATE), 
    CAST(0x0000A17F00000000 AS DATETIME)` it is clear these are binary values exported from SQL Server.

Comment: yeah may be am wrong

Comment: actually i added that tag with same line of thoughts of @martinsmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have looks as though it parses SQL Server `datetime` values ([though incorrectly if they have any time part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4946759/73226)).

This looks like a SQL Server binary `date` format.

[image]

These are stored differently. They occupy three bytes and represents the number of days since `0001-01-01` as a byte reversed integer.

You can use

```
SELECT 
      CAST(
          '0001-01-01 00:00:00' + 
          INTERVAL CAST(CONV(
                        CONCAT(substr(HEX(BinaryData),5,2),
                               substr(HEX(BinaryData),3,2),
                               substr(HEX(BinaryData),1,2))
                        , 16, 10)  AS SIGNED) DAY 
      AS DATE) AS converted_date
FROM
(
SELECT 0xE3350B00 AS BinaryData
) d
```

Which evaluates to `2012-07-08`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/38150)

Comment: Thank Martin... Great help for me. It would give more confident if you can verify that following conversion is right which i did 0x0000A17F00000000 => 2013-03-12

Comment: @AbhinavBhardwaj - That's correct for a SQL Server `datetime` - but the code in your question will only work correctly if the time part is zero. The integer in the time portion is `1/300` of a second. Not minutes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946292/how-to-cast-the-hexadecimal-to-varchardatetime/4946759#4946759 for correct code.

Comment: I am using following for datetime:
return CAST(
      '1900-01-01 00:00:00' + 
      INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX(dttm),1,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED) DAY +
      INTERVAL CAST(CONV(substr(HEX(dttm),9,8), 16, 10)  AS SIGNED)* 10000/3 MICROSECOND
AS DATETIME);

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving it!