# LIKE operator on timestamp column, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, rowversion, sql-timestamp

How can I use `LIKE` operator on a column having timestamp (rowversion) data type ?

Below are the queries I tried but no luck.

```
-- no data is fetched using this SQL
SELECT * FROM TAB
WHERE tRowVersion LIKE '0x000000000000E05%'

-- incorrect syntax near %
SELECT * FROM TAB
WHERE tRowVersion LIKE 0x000000000000E05%
```

Also, I cannot use the single quotes with the timestamp values.

```
-- implicit conversion from data type varchar to timestamp is not allowed
SELECT * FROM TAB
WHERE tRowVersion = '0x000000000000E05'
```

I would like to find the patterns of row versioning using `LIKE` operator. Using `CAST` I am not able to find the patterns.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: may be I am missing something but how is `rowversion` a `timestamp` column?

Comment: @Utsav, the actual column name is tRowVersion with the timestamp data type.

Comment: but what up with hexadecimal values? Are you storing it that way? Or they are just displayed like it.

Comment: Timestamp is a synonym for rowversion - Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. Every time that a row with a rowversion column is modified or inserted, the incremented database rowversion value is inserted in the rowversion column.

Comment: LIKE operator will work on string data. You can CAST your timestamp to varchar or char and then use the like operator on this value.

Comment: Looks like you first have to convert `hex` `timestamp` to `datetime` and then convert it to `varchar` and then you can use `like` operator. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946292/how-to-cast-the-hexadecimal-to-varchardatetime)

Comment: I would like to find the patterns of row versioning using LIKE operator. Using CAST I am not able to find the patterns. Could you explain please ? If I cast the row version as a date-time, with what value should I compare the row version column ?

Comment: Can you let me know what is wrong with my answer? Thanks.

Comment: hey @strickt01 Sorry dude :( bit busy in something. Definitely will try your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rowversion (of which timestamp is a deprecated synonym) is a binary datatype. It has nothing to do with `datetime`s. As such `CAST`ing the hexidecimal string representation of the values to datetime/string in order to perform a `LIKE` will not work. You need to calculate instead which binary values will have hexidecimal string representations starting with the input string.

Assuming a length of 18 for the full rowversion hex string then you could pad out the rest of your input string with `0`s to get the minimum value the `LIKE` should return (were it to work with hex strings - which it doesn't). The maximum value would then either be a pad with `F`s or a case of adding (16 to the power of the amount of characters being filtered by the `LIKE` - 1):

```
DECLARE @string_to_like varchar(18) = '0x000000000000E05'

DECLARE @chars_to_like int
SELECT @chars_to_like = 18 - len(@string_to_like)

DECLARE @min_rowversion_s varchar(18)
SET @min_rowversion_s =  left(ltrim(@string_to_like) + '00000000000000000', 18)

DECLARE @min_rowversion varbinary(8)
SET @min_rowversion = CONVERT(varbinary(8), @min_rowversion_s, 1) 

DECLARE @max_value  INT
DECLARE @divider int

SET @divider = POWER(16, @chars_to_like)

SELECT @max_value = @min_rowversion + @divider - 1

SELECT * FROM TAB WHERE tRowVersion BETWEEN @min_rowversion AND @max_value
```

This would get you the results you need i.e. for `0x000000000000E05` everything between `0x000000000000E050` and `0x000000000000E05F`, for `0x000000000000E` everything between `0x000000000000E000` and `0x000000000000EFFF` etc.

You can then wrap the logic in a UDF as necessary.

Comment: Excellent. Perfect answer :). Works fine for me. Thanks for the efforts ;)