# Importing Dates from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, import

I have a SQL Dump file form a MS SQL server with DateTimes in this format:

```
CAST(0x0000A56100000000 AS DateTime)
```

And I need to import this data to MySQL. How can I convert that to MySQL date format? If its necessary I can use PHP to transform it

Comment: I think this has been answered here: [how to cast the hexadecimal to varchar(datetime)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946292/how-to-cast-the-hexadecimal-to-varchardatetime)

Comment: indeed :) how can I link this question to it?

Comment: Well, you can either post an answer with citation and link or delete the question or wait for a member with 3000+ reputation to mark it as duplicate and delete it. :-)