# Postgresql cast hexadecimal to timestamp (when migrating from SQL Server)

Tags: database, postgresql, type-conversion, sql-insert

I have the following problem when parsing SQL Server insert queries to PostgresSQL. After making the necessary changes to the queries in order for the SQL statements to work, I have been having some troubles with the `CAST()` function.

```
CAST(x00009DD500000000 AS timestamp)
```

1. If I write `CAST(0x000....)`, pgAdmin says that there is a syntax error near x
2. If I remove the 0, I get the error that the column does not exist

I was thinking it could be an error with the amount of columns, but since I am working with a lot of data and I haven't been able to see a function which converts a hexadecimal to timestamp in postgresql, I wanted to know if that could be causing some other kind of error. Maybe?

Is there a function to convert an hexadecimal value to timestamp in Postgresql?

Because converting the hexadecimal value to another type of data would take to much time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of "timestamp" is `x00009DD500000000` supposed to be?

Comment: unfortunately the only thing postgresql can convert hex to is bytea.

Answer (score 1):

This timestamp notation is specific for MSSQL. It has two parts:

- date part - days since 1900-01-01
- time part - with 1/300s precision

There is no automatic cast for this value in PostgreSQL.
Exact solution you can find here:
[how to cast the hexadecimal to varchar(datetime)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946292/how-to-cast-the-hexadecimal-to-varchardatetime)