# How to migrate Data from SQL Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

I know that is a lot of manual work to translate the SQL queries from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. But I was wondering, if there is the more effective way to insert DateTime values from SQL Server to timestamp format in PostgreSQL. Because I need to work with 900 entries.

SQL Server format:

```
CAST(0x00009DFE00000000 AS DateTime)
```

POSTGRESQL format:

```
???
```

Comment: What kind of "date time" is `0x00009DFE00000000` supposed to be?

Comment: How is this different than you other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647909/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use any kind of neutral dump tool, I've personally used this one:

https://github.com/yamldb/yaml_db

for migrations between databases, never used it with SQL Server but provided there is an active record adapter for SQL SERVER it should work too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are limited to use only queries or commands, but if not you may wanna try do some ETL.
There are many tools you could use. I did some simple data migration from SQL server to PostgreSQL a few years ago with Pentaho ETL.

[Pentaho Kettle](https://community.hitachivantara.com/docs/DOC-1009855-data-integration-kettle)

Comment: 1. Is there any specific requirement for my pc to work with Pentaho ETL?       2. I am not allowed to manipulate data of the SQL Server as i am just migrating the information to test out one app of our company with the POSTGRESQL service, so is there any special consideration on how to handle this process?

Comment: Does this work well with complex data entries? For example i have tables with 90 columns and aproximately 900 entries for each one

Comment: I don't think you should worry about the pc requirements. If you can run MSSQL or PgAdmin i think you're good to go. Here's the user guide of the graphical tool https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Spoon+User+Guide

You must get access to the db instance so you can do the ETL

And about the data, you mean complex data or large data?